# Elementary Symmetric Polynomials and Determinant

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, galois-theory, symmetric-polynomials

I am trying to show that
\begin{equation}
\sqrt{\Delta} = \prod\limits_{1 \leq i < j \leq n} \left( x_i - x_j \right)
= \det \begin{pmatrix} \dfrac{\partial \sigma_{n,1}}{\partial x_1} & \cdots & \dfrac{\partial \sigma_{n,n}}{\partial x_1} \\ \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\ \dfrac{\partial \sigma_{n,1}}{\partial x_n} & \cdots & \dfrac{\partial \sigma_{n,n}}{\partial x_n} \end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}
where $\sigma_{n,j}$ are the elementary symmetric polynomials of $n$ variables $x_1, x_2, · · · , x_n$ Does anyone know of another method to do so other than induction since I am not sure how the inductive step works out~

Comment: What is $\Delta$? Do you want to prove both equations?

Comment: The determinant is an alternating function of the $x_i$, so is divisible by your product. What could the quotient be?

Comment: For your second equation: I shall use the notation $e_j$ for the $j$-th [elementary symmetric polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_symmetric_polynomial) of any set of variables, and the notation $h_j$ for the $j$-th [complete homogeneous symmetric polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complete_homogeneous_symmetric_polynomial) of any set of variables. Then, your $\sigma_{n,j}$ is $e_j\left(x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n\right)$, whereas the entries $\dfrac{\partial \sigma_{n,j}}{\partial x_i}$ of your matrix can be rewritten as $e_{j-1}\left(\widehat{x_i}\right)$. Here, ...

Comment: ... I am using "$\widehat{x_i}$" as a shorthand for the $\left(n-1\right)$-tuple $\left(x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_{i-1}, x_{i+1}, x_{i+2}, \ldots, x_n\right)$ which contains all your $n$ variables but for $x_i$. Let me denote your matrix by $A$; thus, the $\left(i, j\right)$-th entry of $A$ is $e_{j-1}\left(\widehat{x_i}\right)$ for all $i$ and $j$. Let me define two other $n\times n$-matrices $B$ and $C$. The matrix $B$ shall be the matrix whose $\left(i,j\right)$-th entry is $\left(-x_i\right)^{j-1}$. This is a Vandermonde matrix, so its determinant ...

Comment: ... is $\det B = \prod\limits_{1 \leq i < j \leq n} \left( x_i - x_j \right)$. The matrix $C$ shall be the matrix whose $\left(i,j\right)$-th entry is $\left(-1\right)^{j-i} h_{j-i}\left(x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n\right)$. Here we follow the standard convention that $h_p = 0$ whenever $p$ is negative, and that $h_0$ is the constant $1$. Thus, the matrix $C$ is upper-triangular (since $h_{j-i} = 0$ when $i > j$), and all its diagonal entries are $1$ (since $h_0 = 1$). Hence, $\det C = 1$. Now, there is a neat identity which I invite you to show: ...

Comment: ... For each $i \in \left\{1,2,\ldots,n\right\}$ and $j \in \left\{1,2,\ldots,n\right\}$, we have $x_i^{j-1} = \sum\limits_{k=1}^n \left(-1\right)^{k-1} e_{k-1}\left(\widehat{x_i}\right) h_{j-k}$. This shows that $A = BC$, and thus $\det A = \det B \cdot \det C$. Conclude using what we know about $\det B$ and $\det C$.

Comment: @darijgrinberg I suggest to write an answer instead of 4 subsequent comments.

Comment: @PaulFrost: with an answer, the many gaps will be way too visible :)

Comment: @darijgrinberg Courage for the gap ;-)

Comment: @darijgrinberg Ah where did your neat identity come from? It looks highly non-trivial to show or is it?

Comment: @Homaniac: One way to get it is from generating functions. For example, Lemma 3.1 in [my *A basis for a quotient of symmetric polynomials*](http://www.cip.ifi.lmu.de/~grinberg/algebra/basisquot.pdf) (alas, very unfinished work, so the numbers are still likely to jump) proves it for $i = n$ (just apply that lemma to $k = n$, $i = n$ and $p = j-1$); but then it follows for all other $i$ automatically (since the polynomials are symmetric and it doesn't matter which variable you choose as $x_i$).

Answer (score 3):

We work over the ring $R=\mathbb{Z}[x_1,\cdots,x_n]$.

Let
$$P=\prod\limits_{1 \leq i < j \leq n} \left( x_i - x_j \right)\in R,\qquad\qquad
D=  \begin{pmatrix} \dfrac{\partial \sigma_{n,1}}{\partial x_1} & \cdots & \dfrac{\partial \sigma_{n,n}}{\partial x_1} \\ \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\ \dfrac{\partial \sigma_{n,1}}{\partial x_n} & \cdots & \dfrac{\partial \sigma_{n,n}}{\partial x_n} \end{pmatrix}\in M_n(R)$$

For $i\neq j$, the $i$'th row of $D$ may be obtained from the $j$'th row, by replacing every occurence of $x_i$ with $x_j$.  Thus if we subtract the $j$'th row from the $i$'th row, we obtain a row where every entry is divisible by $x_i-x_j$.  As the determinant of the matrix is invariant under such operations, we see that ${\rm Det}(D)$ is divisible by $x_i-x_j$ for all $i\neq j$.

As $R$ is a UFD, we conclude that $P$ divides ${\rm Det}(D)$.  That is we have some $C\in R$ with $PC={\rm Det}(D)$.

Write $C=C_0+\cdots+C_k$, where each $C_i$ is a homogeneous element of $R$, of degree $i$.  Note that both $P$ and ${\rm Det}(D)$  are homogeneous elements of $R$ of degree $n(n-1)/2$.  As the product of two homogeneous elements of $R$, of degrees $i,j$ is a non-zero homogeneous element of $R$ of degree $i+j$, we see that $C=C_0\in \mathbb{Z}$.

---

**Edit** I originally showed $C_0=1$ through direct calculation of a coefficient. This calculation remains intact below this edit.  However a slicker method by induction was pointed out by @user26857 and explained by @dxiv (see their comments below).  Their method:

Let $R_n=R, P_n=P, c_n=C_0, D_n=D$.  We argue by induction.  Suppose we have shown that $c_{n-1}=1$, so that $P_{n-1}={\rm Det}(D_{n-1})$.  We will show that $c_n=1$.

Let $\phi\colon R_n \to R_{n-1}$ denote the map sending $x_n\mapsto 0$ and restricting to the identity on $R_{n-1}$.

Then $\phi(P_n)=x_1\cdots x_{n-1} P_{n-1}$ and $\phi(D_n)$ is the matrix $D_{n-1}$ with an extra row and column attached at the end, where the only non-zero entry in the final column is the diagonal entry $x_1\cdots x_{n-1}$ at the bottom.

We have: \begin{eqnarray}\phi(P_n)&=&c_n{\,\,\rm Det}(\phi(D_n))\\&=&c_nx_1\cdots x_{n-1}{\,\,\rm Det}(D_{n-1})\\&=&c_n x_1\cdots x_{n-1}P_{n-1}\\&=&c_n\phi(P_n),\end{eqnarray}
so $c_n=1$ as required.

For the base case note that $$(x_1-x_2)={\,\rm Det}\left(\begin{array}{cc} 1&x_2\\1&x_1\end{array}\right).$$

---

**Original proof that $C_0=1$:**

The coefficient in $P$ on $x_1^{n-1}x_2^{n-2}\cdots x_{n-1}$ is $1$.  We must show that the corresponding coefficient on ${\rm Det}(D)$ is also $1$.

We have $D_{ij}= \dfrac{\partial \sigma_{n,j}}{\partial x_i}$, which is the sum of all products of $j-1$ distinct $x_r$, with each $r\neq i$.  We now consider the expansion of ${\rm Det}(D)$, as a sum over permutations $\sigma\in S_n$ of products $\epsilon_\sigma D_{1\sigma_1}\cdots D_{n\sigma_n}$. (Here $\epsilon_\sigma$ denotes the sign of the permutation $\sigma$).

How can the monomial $x_1^{n-1}x_2^{n-2}\cdots x_{n-1}$ arise in this expansion?  That is, how can we obtain this monomial, by multiplying together one monomial from $D_{i\sigma_i}$, for $i=1,\cdots,n$?

Firstly, for the exponent on $x_1$ to be $n-1$, we must have $\sigma_1=1$, so that we get a factor of $x_1$ from each column other than the first, which cannot contribute such a factor.

In particular, the monomial picked up from the second column must be $x_1$, so for the exponent on $x_2$ to be $n-2$ we must have $\sigma_2=2$, and there must be a factor of $x_2$ in each monomial picked up from later columns.

Again this means that the monomial picked up from the third column is $x_1x_2$, so $\sigma_3=3$ and there is a factor of $x_3$ in the monomials picked up from all subsequent columns.

Repeating this argument for each column, we conclude that the only occurrence of $x_1^{n-1}x_2^{n-2}\cdots x_{n-1}$, in the expansion of ${\rm Det}(D)$ occurs in the $\sigma=$Id term, as the product of monomials $$1x_1(x_1x_2)(x_1x_2x_3)\cdots (x_1x_2x_3\cdots x_{n-1}).$$

Thus the coefficient on $x_1^{n-1}x_2^{n-2}\cdots x_{n-1}$ in ${\rm Det}(D)$ is $1$ as required.

Comment: $C_0$ should be the same for every $n$, isn't it? Then why don't check that it is 1 for $n=2$?

Comment: @user26857 Why is $C_0$ independent of $n$?

Comment: @tkf Once you have $\,D_n = C_{0,n} \cdot \prod_{i \lt j} (x_i-x_j)\,$, you can set $\,x_n=0\,$ so that the last column of the determinant will have only one non-zero element, then it follows that $\,C_{0,n} = C_{0,n-1}\,$.

Comment: @dxiv Thanks, I have added an edit to the answer, acknowledging this method.